# Adding EBS volume on hadoop single node cluster

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, storage, instance

I have created an `EC2` Linux machine on `AWS` cloud with `8 GB` root volume and then deployed hadoop and spark and created **Single Node** cluster on that machine.

When I open the home page of the hadoop, I see all good.

```
Configured Capacity:    7.74 GB
DFS Used:   3.72 MB (0.05%)
Non DFS Used:   4.47 GB
DFS Remaining:  3.27 GB (42.23%)
Block Pool Used:    3.72 MB (0.05%)
```

So far, all good. Now I want to add more storage on this EC2 instance. So I have taken an **EBS block storage of 40GB** and create an **ext4** file system on it and mount it to **/data** directory of the EC2 instance.
using **df -h** command, I can see the space is all mounted and correctly available.
`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
 udev            3.9G   12K  3.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           799M  400K  799M   1% /run
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  4.1G  3.3G  56% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/xvdb        40G   48M   38G   1% /data
```

But on the hadoop page `(http://*<myec2-ip>*:50050/)`, I still see the same `7.74GB` capacity and doesn't see the increased capacity.

I have even tried to re-format the hadoop file system but this doesn't help either.
**bin/hadoop namenode -format**

How can I add this additional storage on the hadoop file system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit the hdfs-site.xml to mount a directory in that new volume to place your namenode or datanode data.

`dfs.datanode.data.dir` - Determines where on the local filesystem an DFS data node should store its blocks. If this is a comma-delimited list of directories, then data will be stored in all named directories, typically on different devices

`dfs.namenode.name.dir` - Determines where on the local filesystem the DFS name node should store the name table(fsimage). If this is a comma-delimited list of directories then the name table is replicated in all of the directories, for redundancy

Then you'll need to restart the respective HDFS services

Try to avoid formatting the namenode. You lose all HDFS data when you do

Comment: Thanks . Please can you confirm what entries I need to make in the hdfs-site.xml file?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Just a quick query, if I have to mount the root directory as well for the machine, should I specify the value of `dfs.datanode.data.dir` as `/data,/` ?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest it. Make an empty subfolder on the root. But yes, it's a comma separated value of directories. For best performance, the datanode volumes should be on separate disks from the OS. Same for log directories

Comment: Thanks. So, i can have datanode on mounted disk and namenode running on root disk for better performance?

Comment: Only the OS should be on the root disk. In a production environment, the namenode is on its own server. The datanode directories, all logs, and OS should each be on independent volumes

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick help.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is the following:

1. Added below config in /etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml file

   ```
   <property>
       <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
       <value>/data</value>
   </property>
   ```

As `/data` is the directory where I mount my new EBS volume to.

2. I stopped the hadoop and yarn service using the folllowing commands:

   ```
   $HADOOP_HOME/sbin/stop-dfs.sh
   $HADOOP_HOME/sbin/stop-yarn.sh
   ```
3. As I am using the **`hadoop`** user to run my hadoop server, I made **`hadoop`** user as owner to /data using the following command

   ```
   sudo chown hadoop /data
   ```
4. I then restarted the hadoop service again.

   ```
   $HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-dfs.sh
   $HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-yarn.sh
   ```